# How do I keep extensibility with private properties?

Tags: c#, interface, delegates, extensibility

I'm working on the following class.  I've shortened the list of properties as an example.

```
public class Paycheck 
{
   public decimal Gross { get; private set; }
   public decimal FederalWithholdingTax { get; private set; }
   public decimal StateWithholdingTax  { get; private set;  }
   // ...
}
```

Now my idea was to create an interface to calculate all the taxes...

```
public interface IPaycheckDeductionCalculator
{
   void Calculate();
}
```

The idea after that is to create methods outside of the Paycheck class that can perform calculations/deductions.  With the way laws and payroll processes work, how deductions are performed and what deductions are performed are constantly changing, so I want to keep extensibility easy.

My dilemma is that I want to keep the Paycheck property setters private so that just anyone can change those values.  Keeping that data constant after a paycheck is processed is critical.

I considered the use of delegates, but I'm not so sure that's my answer either, as I still wouldn't be able to develop the desired methods outside of the Paycheck class.

Is there something I'm not thinking of or is this a "you can't have your cake and eat it too" kind of situation?

Comment: Can you create a class that implements that interface and then instantiate a `Paycheck` class inside the `Calculate` method, thus initializing the values through the `Paycheck` constructor?

Comment: I considered this, but I would then have to initialize a new class for every property and then I would have to have some way of reducing all those classes to one.  The Calculate method is only responsible for calculating one property of the Paycheck class.

Answer (score 1):

Have the interfaces that calculate these values return the values that they are calculating.  Pass in instances of these interfaces to `Paycheck`, which can the perform the calculations (without needing to know anything about the implementation of the interface) and then have it set the values of the appropriate properties.

Comment: This makes sense.  How would I implement that in the Paycheck class though?  I could inject interfaces into the class to perform the calculation and return the value, but the Paycheck class would have to know which property the interface wants to modify.

Comment: @Safari137 Give the interface several methods, one to compute each property.  Or have it accept interfaces for each property, as you said.